# Typescript & React/JSX: JSX element attributes type 'T' must be an object type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

Using typescript 1.8.10 with VS 2015 and getting the following error while attempting to use react-router:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router, browserHistory } from "react-router";
import routes from "./routes"; //get default

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory} />,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

routes (from "./routes")

```
import App from "./components/App";

export default {
    component: "div",
    childRoutes: [{
        path: "/",
        component: App,
    }]
};
```

[error image: JSX element attributes type 'T' must be an object type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j79Ex.png)

Comment: Show your routes.tsx contents.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't importing your routes object correctly. Since you are using `export default` you must use [default import syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Importing_defaults):

```
import routes from "./routes";
```

Comment: Thank you for helping.  The error persists even with the new import for routes (updated screenshot above)

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(Router, routes)`?

Answer (score 0):

At this point, this error doesn't stop typescript from compiling your code down to JS so I'm just ignoring the error within the VS 2015 IDE.  It's really just an annoying red squiggly when it comes down to it...